# Converting Ruby regexs to Java

Tags: java, ruby, regex

I'm getting back into Java programming and after looking at the docs it appears there is no simple way of implementing the following Ruby regexps. Can anyone help me convert the following functionality to Java, or at least point me to a good resource?

```
some_string = "ruby$|java$"

text.match(/#{some_string}/i)

text.gsub(/^ny\b/i, " new york ")
```

Comment: What have you tried? How was it not efficient enough? Why are you certain that there is a faster implementation that what you've done already?

Comment: There's no current Java implementation. I'm getting back into Java after a several-year hiatus and was hoping someone would provide a straightforward solution, as I'm having trouble finding any close equivalents to that in the docs. I'll revise my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bevanb,

Check out the [regexp lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) in the Java Tutorials.  There's a lot there, but of particular interest is the "Pattern Method Equivalents in java.lang.String" section at the bottom of the "[Methods of the Pattern Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)" page.  A quick skim of that section suggests:

- For "match," use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)
- For "replace," use [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Good luck!